# Problem with class variables , to use them in if block in function

Tags: php, class, function

I am having problem in accessing variables in class here's the code

```
class Text {

      private $text = '';

      private $words = '';
      // function to initialise $words
      private  function filterText($value,$type) {
          $words = $this->words;
          echo count($words); // works returns a integer
          if($type == 'length') {
              echo count($words); // not works returns 0
          }
          $this->words = $array;
      }
      // even this fails 
      public function filterMinCount($count) {
         $words = $this->words;
         echo count($words);
         if(true){
           echo 'bingo'.count($words);
         }
      }
}
```

Can any one tell me the reason

Comment: why do you do that anyway, if you have another variable you can use?

Answer (score 0):

Only obvious thing I notice:

The line `$this->words = $array;` in `Text::filterText()` is wrong.

You are setting the internal attribute to an undefined variable (`$array`) so  `$this->words` gets set to `null`. Thus, the next time you call `count($this->words)` it will return `0`.

Secondly - as the other people have asked - **please post the whole code as you use it**.

Answer (score 0):

Variable "$array" is missing. Then:

```
<?php
    echo count( '' ); // 1
    echo count( null ); // 0
?>
```

Maybe this is the problem?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I've just done a bit of rewriting with a constructor and some dummy data, I've copied the source below and used the constructor to demonstrate the output and the fact that it is using class variables.

Firstly the $word variable is defined as an array and I’ve just populated it with two pieces of data to prove it works, the constructor then calls `$this->filterText("", "length")` which outputs 2 twice which is correct as the array has two strings in it. The $word array is then reset to contain 5 values and the constructor then calls `$this->filterMinCount(0)` which outputs 5 which is also correct.

Output :

> 22
>
> 5bingo5

Hope this helps

class Text
{

```
private $text = '';

private $words = array('1', '2');

function __construct()
{
    //calling this function outputs 2, as this is the size of the array
    $this->filterText("", "length");

    echo "<br />";

    $this->filterMinCount(0);
}

// function to initialise $words
private function filterText($value,$type) 
{
    $words = $this->words;

    echo count($words); // works returns a integer

    if($type == 'length') 
    {
        echo count($words); // not works returns 0
    }

    //reset the array
    $this->words = array(1,2,3,4,5);
}

// even this fails 
public function filterMinCount($count) 
{
    $words = $this->words;

    echo count($words);

    if(true)
    {
        echo 'bingo'.count($words);
    }
}
```

}